# Curl in vagrant to reference itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, vagrant

I currently have a project running on a Ubuntu virtual machine on my computer. I am using Vagrant and Virtual Box to set up this environment and have the Puma server up and running with the command:

```
bundle exec puma
```

Which provided the following output:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
D [2016-07-04 11:26:23 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (reschedule) queue
D [2016-07-04 11:26:25 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (trial) queue
D [2016-07-04 11:26:25 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (free) queue
D [2016-07-04 11:26:25 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (renew) queue
D [2016-07-04 11:26:25 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (renew_charge_response) queue
D [2016-07-04 11:26:25 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (merchant_notification) queue
D [2016-07-04 11:26:25 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (renew_charge) queue
D [2016-07-04 11:26:25 $2728] DEBUG | : Register a receiver for (partial_renew_charge) queue
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I wish to now be able to make calls to this via curl commands. At present I am able to curl to the live API which leads me to believe that my curl command is correct however when i do the same to my test environment, contained within my virtual machine I get an error referring to "Basic Auth required". From this I am assuming that I am hitting the API correctly as the error returned is one contained within the API code. My problem is Basic Authentication as I have created a user and password in my environment. I have base64 encoded this and fed the resulting string into my curl statement like below:

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:9292/v2.2/ -H "Authorization: Basic cGF5bWVudHM6cGF5bWVudHM="
```

For some reason it is not being accepted. Can anyway provide me with some indication as to how I could go about diagnosing the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you need to encode the password - try this:

`curl --user name:password http://localhost:9292/v2.2/`

just substitute your user name and password.

source: 
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Basic_Authentication

Comment: Think both can be done but had tried both already. I think this is an issue specific to the application however I cant really share the application code. Thanks for the input though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must forward port 9292 from guest to vm. You should have something like in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9292, host: 9292
```

then you should be able to run `curl` command from your host machine